# Bash script exits early after installing oh my zsh

Tags: bash, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to install oh my zsh and a few other commands using a bash script.

However, after installing oh my zsh, the bash script exits without running the rest of the script.

Bash script snippet:

```sh
echo Installing Oh My Zsh
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
echo Installing zeit theme
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vercel/zsh-theme/master/vercel.zsh-theme -Lo ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/vercel.zsh-theme
echo Installing Node.js
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
source ~/.zshrc
nvm install node
nvm use node
npm install -g yarn
```

Is there a way for me to maybe prevent the oh my zsh install script to exit when the installation is complete.

Thanks !

Comment: What is `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash` supposed to do? Security-wise it looks like a *very* bad idea.

Comment: install node version manager, however the script doesn't get to that part

Comment: What exactly happens when you run it? What output & errors do you get? Also, it looks like you're trying to execute commands from a zsh script (~/.zshrc) in bash, which probably won't work very well.

Comment: Maybe run the script as `bash -x script` and post the output.

Comment: @GordonDavisson There's no error output per se, the only output I get from running the script is saying that Oh my zsh... is now installed. and I'm back to my HOME directory

Comment: A *`bash`* script should not be sourcing a `zsh` configuration file.

Comment: `source ~/.zshrc` in a _bash_ script?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh My Zsh provides an "Unattended Install" Option: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh#unattended-install

According to the docs:

> If you're running the Oh My Zsh install script as part of an automated install, you can pass the flag --unattended to the install.sh script. This will have the effect of not trying to change the default shell, and also won't run zsh when the installation has finished.

In my case, the script in use had a small mistake.

Required:

```
bash -c "... curl command ..." "" --unattended
```

What was there:

```
bash -c "... curl command ..." --unattended
```

Note the missing `""` in my command before the `--unattended` flag.

Once I added this, the Oh My Zsh installation didn't cause the bash script to exit early.

Comment: BTW, personally, I'd put `bash` in place of the `""`. That leads to better error messages, as `$0` is used at the front of messages from the shell. (`bash: whatever error here` instead of just `: whatever error here`)